# Making code more generic

Tags: go

I have a program where many functionalities are similar across different structures, however, I end up writing these functions again and again, esp because the variable that are being dealt inside are of different structures.

I have written a sample code here.

[In Go Playgroud](https://play.golang.org/p/R2kZb_X5Kl)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func (a *Match) Add(v Match) {
    a.Runs += v.Runs
    a.Points += v.Points
}

type Match struct {
    Runs   uint64
    Points uint64
}

func (a *Activity) Add(v Activity) {
    a.Walk += v.Walk
    a.Jog += v.Jog
}

type Activity struct {
    Walk uint64
    Jog  uint64
}

func GetDailyMatches() map[string]Match {
    var dailyMatches map[string]Match

    Match1, Match2 := Match{5, 10}, Match{1, 2}
    dailyMatches = make(map[string]Match)
    dailyMatches["01"] = Match1
    dailyMatches["02"] = Match2
    dailyMatches["03"] = Match1
    dailyMatches["04"] = Match2
    return dailyMatches
}

func GetDailyActivities() map[string]Activity {
    var dailyActivities map[string]Activity

    Activity1, Activity2 := Activity{5, 10}, Activity{1, 2}
    dailyActivities = make(map[string]Activity)
    dailyActivities["01"] = Activity1
    dailyActivities["02"] = Activity2
    dailyActivities["03"] = Activity1
    dailyActivities["04"] = Activity2
    return dailyActivities
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(CalculateMatchSummary("01", "03"))
    fmt.Println(CalculateActivitySummary("02", "04"))
    fmt.Println(CalculateMatchSummary("01", "03"))
    fmt.Println(CalculateActivitySummary("02", "04"))
}

func CalculateMatchSummary(start, end string) (total Match) {
    dailyMatches := GetDailyMatches()
    for day, value := range dailyMatches {
        if day < start {
            continue
        } else if day > end {
            continue
        } else {
            total.Add(value)
        }
    }
    return
}

func CalculateActivitySummary(start, end string) (total Activity) {
    dailyActivities := GetDailyActivities()
    for day, value := range dailyActivities {
        if day < start {
            continue
        } else if day > end {
            continue
        } else {
            total.Add(value)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

If you notice, both `Match` and `Activity` has the same functions and same structures, except that internally they are of different structures.

Is there a easy way to make the code more generic (Go generics, which is not there in Go??) in Golang itself.

Comment: you could just put the if block in a method..

Comment: @ergonaut the `total` type is different. Will it still work?

Comment: I guess not.  https://golang.org/doc/faq#generics

Comment: @ergonaut yes, I realise that `generics` is not supported. But any workarounds till that time. Any other intelligent ways to handle this. I thought golang did not add generics, because, there are other ways to do it. Is it not true?

Comment: Sorry I don't know go.  But you go search "polymorphism golang" which may give you ideas.

Comment: Are the two data structures really coupled? In other words, should changing one's base functionality change the other? If they are, you can have them share a data storage type and use composition. If not, go's design encourages liberal use of lightweight interfaces. This may be a situation where you want to rework the code so that both data types have a common interface, and can thus both be used in the same method.

Comment: @MikePrecup `Match` and `Activity` are two completely separate items. They do not have any common items between them. Changing one, should not have an effect on other. Did I understand your question on `coupled` correctly? If not, can you please explain more on what coupled really means here. I’m looking more about having a common interface, but I’m not able to figure out how to get interface work in this case. You see, here, we have a for loop, looping over a map. And the input (the `dailyActivities` or `dailyMatches`) comes from a different function. The `total.Add` is not common. Any tips?

Comment: I take back what I said, I'm not sure you can use interfaces here without side effects since you're taking an argument of the same type, I missed that. I can't come up with a clean way to do this while maintaining the current code design. You may be able to fix this by redesigning from the original problem as opposed to the current solution. The golang source is the gold standard for go design, and should be trusted more than anything I say.

Answer (score 1):

Go has a pretty package "reflect". You can **not** do genericity strictly speaking but you can get unification of code for the same behavior.
I've changed your playground a bit : https://play.golang.org/p/bfqZsFOgVQ

The main part :

```
func AddTwo(a, b interface{}) interface{} {
    va := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    vb := reflect.ValueOf(b)
    res := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(a)).Elem()
    if va.Kind() != reflect.Struct && vb.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return nil
    }

    na, nb := va.NumField(), vb.NumField()
    if na != nb {
        return nil
    }

    for i := 0; i < na; i++ {
        // additional verification needed here
        fa := va.Field(i).Uint()
        fb := vb.Field(i).Uint()
        fr := fa + fb
        res.Field(i).SetUint(fr)
    }

    return res.Interface()
}
```

I use reflect to check the fields of the struct I am given. If both are uint64, I can add them reflectively. If your structs contains many uint64, it can add them all !

Note that you must convert the resulting interface to the type of the struct given after calling this function. That is why this is not strictly generic, because the returning type is a interface, and not a Match or Activity.

**EDIT**: No need even to return a new struct. You can simply update the field of the "a" struct by calling .SetUint() method.